# How to assign a random value to a data attribute from a given array during v-for in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

On my main Vue instance I have a data attribute that is an array. It has 4 items:

```
var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            efeitosAos: ['fade', 'flip-up', 'slide-up', 'zoom-in'],
            aos: 'fade-in'
}
```

As you can see, it has names of effects from the [AOS](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) library. My idea is to get a random value from it and pass it to one of my components.

Each component is called inside a **v-for**:

```
<post v-for="post, index in posts" :key="post.id" :post="post" :efeito="aos">
    {{randomizaAos()}}
</post>
```

This is my component:

```
const post = {
   data: function(){
        return {
            duration: 1000,
            delay: 50,
        }
    },

    props: {
        efeito: '',
        post: {
            id: '',
            titulo: '',
            resumo: '',
            imagem: '',
        },
    },
    template: '\
        <section class="guarda-post" :data-aos="efeito" :data-aos-duration="duration" :data-aos-delay="delay">\
        <img :src="post.imagem" class="img-fluid">\
        <h4 class="titulo-post">{{post.titulo}}</h4>\
        <p>{{post.resumo}}</p>\
        </section>'
};
```

On my component, I have a **prop** called **efeito**. It should receive the value of my data **aos**, that comes from my **main Vue instance**. My idea is to use a method to change this aos data. So far, I got this:

```
methods:{
        randomizaAos: function(){
           var efeitoAleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.efeitosAos.length);
           this.aos = this.efeitosAos[efeitoAleatorio];
           console.log(this.aos);
        }
}
```

The problem is that when I run the **randomizaAos** method, I get an infinite loop, and I don't know why. It's weird, because if I leave only the console.log inside the method, I get 4 messages, that is precisely the size of my **posts** array. But when I use the Math stuff and give to my aos data the value found, I get the infinite loop. Why is that? Any help?

Comment: `post` isn't declared as a vue component

Comment: It is, I just didn't put all the content of my main Vue instance.

Comment: why not use `randomizaAos()` in the mounted method

Comment: Mounted would run only once, right? I need a new random value each iteration of the v-for. And if I do a mounted method inside the component (this solves the problem), I cant use the randomizaAos function on my other components.

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of the efeito prop in the mounted method, so it won't be re-renderized everytime

Comment: Wouldn't mounted give me only one value? I need a new random value for efeito every interation of the v-for.